# Why Process is Restarting Automatically?

Tags: android, process, pid

My android application has a activity and, a service running in same process. I had launched my app and i am in my Landing activity. My service is also running, now if i press device back button the process ID (PID) of my application is changing, as i feel the Process is killed and recreated. There is no low memory scenario or any Task manager problems for killing my app. I couldnt get a solution or valid reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

May be the development options of the phone? I think there was one that limited the number of background processes

Comment: It is in standard limit only. What is the number for Standard limit?

Comment: I think the standard limit is not related to a number but a memory limit, Android start killing services first when it is running out of memory http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html